# Return the _.maxBy value for more than one object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I can return the highest value of one object from my data by doing the below:

```
highest = Math.ceil(_.maxBy(stats, 'success' ).success );
```

This returns the success value. But I want the highest value returned from whichever is higher from "success" and "unsuccessful" objects. (more than one object)

Something like this:

```
highest = Math.ceil(_.maxBy((stats, 'success' ).success ) && ((stats, 'unsuccessful' ).unsuccessful));

const stats = [{ success: 52 }, { unsuccessful: 65 }];
```

In this scenarios I expect highest would return "65"

Comment: Do you want the solution using lodash only?

Comment: `Math.max( _.maxBy(stats, 'success' ).success, _.maxBy(stats, 'unsuccessful' ).unsuccessful );`

Comment: Thanks @JJJ the above was what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it in lodash, using [`lodash#map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#map) and [`lodash#max`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#max) to get the highest for both `success` and `unsuccessful` values.

```
const result = _(stats)
  .map(v => _.max([v.success, v.unsuccessful]))
  .max();
```

```js
const stats = [{ success: 52 }, { unsuccessful: 65 }, { success: 0 }];

const result = _(stats)
  .map(v => _.max([v.success, v.unsuccessful]))
  .max();
  
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;top:0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```